# Documents and Reports unavailable for AD account

Tags: tfs, active-directory

Documents and Reports are unavailable when I log in with my AD account. I also can't add new team project with my AD account even when its set as TSF administrator, I get TF30224 permission error for the tfsservice account. These all work when I log in TFS server local Administrator account.

TFS service runs under domain\account.

How can I make these work with AD accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add permission for your domain account to Reporting Servies and Sharepoint seperatly.

One way to do this if you are an Admin is to go to "Team Foundation Administration Console | Application Tier | Administration Console Users | Add" and add your domain account. This will automaticaly add you to TFS, SQL, RS and Sharepoint if it is a local instance. If it is a seperate instance of sharepoint you will need to add yourself manualy.

The TFSService account should also be an admin on Sharepoint and Reporting Serivcves. the exact permissions are listed in the documentation Guide:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=07AA12E5-2ED3-4DB8-96EB-51A48DCCB35D&displaylang=en